# configuring a webpart manually

Tags: data-view-web-part

does anyone know how to configure this webspart to pull data from my "test" sharepoint list? http://wicklunddataformwp.codeplex.com/

1. I deployed the webpart mannually but compiling the class file and
   deploying the dll to the gac then
2. uploading the webpart to the webpart gallery and publishing it.
3. now i have the webart on my home page, i cut and pasted the sample xsl code but i
   can't figure out where to point it to my sharepoint list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the code, you can't point directly to a SharePoint list, you need to point it to the SharePoint Webservices.  Those elements are the one you need to fill :

```
#region WebPartProperties
    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("Path to the WSDL file for the web service"),
    FriendlyName("WsdlPath"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string WsdlPath
    {
        get
        {
            return wsdlPath;
        }

        set
        {
            wsdlPath = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("See DataFormWebPart documentation..."),
    FriendlyName("Select Action"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string SelectAction
    {
        get
        {
            return selectAction;
        }

        set
        {
            selectAction = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("See DataFormWebPart documentation..."),
    FriendlyName("Select Service Name"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string SelectServiceName
    {
        get
        {
            return selectServiceName;
        }

        set
        {
            selectServiceName = value;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("See DataFormWebPart documentation..."),
    FriendlyName("Select Url"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string SelectUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return selectUrl;
        }

        set
        {
            selectUrl = value;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("See DataFormWebPart documentation..."),
    FriendlyName("Select Port"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string SelectPort
    {
        get
        {
            return selectPort;
        }

        set
        {
            selectPort = value;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("Enter the name of the method in the web service to call..."),
    FriendlyName("Web Service Method Name"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string WebServiceMethodName
    {
        get
        {
            return webServiceMethodName;
        }

        set
        {
            webServiceMethodName = value;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("See DataFormWebPart documentation..."),
    FriendlyName("Web Service Method Namespace"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string WebServiceMethodNamespace
    {
        get
        {
            return webServiceMethodNamespace;
        }

        set
        {
            webServiceMethodNamespace = value;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue(defaultvalue),
    Description("Enter optional parameters that may be needed for the web service - eg. \"<EnumName>EnumA</EnumName>"),
    FriendlyName("Select Service Name"),
    ReadOnly(false),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string WebServiceMethodParameters
    {
        get
        {
            return webServiceMethodParameters;
        }

        set
        {
            webServiceMethodParameters = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

For your info, the web service you do need should be this one : http://servername:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx and the method to use would be [Lists.GetLisItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Have fun!